# Ng-click doesn't work with HTML5 video scrubber bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, undefined, angularjs-ng-click

I have been following thenewboston's HTML5 video tutorials and have been trying to change bits to use AngularJS. However, I am having trouble with the bar not updating when you click in a different place than where its currently playing at.

My code:

https://github.com/IdrisAbdul-Hussein/portfolio2.git

Essentially, I have a video.html file which loads the video player etc (video.html is included in the repo) which looks like this:

```
<div id="big_wrapper">
    <section id="skin">
    <video id="myMovie" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="videos/testVideo.mp4"/>
    </video>
        <nav>
            <div id="buttons">
                <button type="button" id="playButton" ng-click="playOrPause()">Play</button>
            </div>
            <div id="defaultBar" ng-click="clickedBar()">
                <div id="progressBar"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </nav>
    </section>
</div>
```

The functions that the ng-click's refer to are in my controller.js.

The error that I'm getting is:

***TypeError: e is undefined***    - controller.js(line 53)

However, when I put `ng-click="clickedBar(this)"` then it gives me the following error:

***Error: Value being assigned to HTMLMediaElement.currentTime is not a finite floating-point value.***     - controller.js(line 55)

I'm not sure which is more in the right direction and not sure how to solve the problem! Been bashing my head trying to fix this problem for a while.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to pass $event to ng-click function except 'this' ?

Comment: Please show your Angular code *here*, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your "e is undefined" error is because your code expects e to contain the click event. `ng-click="clickedBar()` does not pass the event to clickedBar. Try `ng-click="clickedBar($event)">` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!!!! Finally =] I don't have enough rep to give a score, but I will come back and rate it when I do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In angular expressions `this` points to current scope object, not to the DOM element like in HTML event attributes.

You need to pass DOM node into your ngClick handler which is available in `$event.target`:

```
ng-click="clickedBar($event.target)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The answer below worked. I'm not sure why yours didn't.